# JavaScript Restful Client for Restful Web Service with NetBeans and Glassfish

Tags: javascript, rest, netbeans, glassfish

There are serious bugs when trying to create a RESTful JavaScript Client with NetBeans and Glassfish within the OpenESB 2.3.1 package. 
I'm trying to create a RESTful JS Client for the RESTful Customer DB Example that comes with NetBeans.

In CustomerDB.js, the init function is blank.

```
init: function() 
{ 
    this.initialized = true; 
},
```

It is supposed to have resources in it, like this:

```
init: function() 
{ 
this.resources[0] = new Rest_customerdb_discountcode(this.uri+'/rest.customerdb.discountcode/'); 
this.resources[1] = new Rest_customerdb_customer(this.uri+'/rest.customerdb.customer'); 
this.initialized = true; 
},
```

Even after adding the resources manually, there is a problem. 
The line: 
var items = resource.getEntities(); 
inside TestStubs.html fails and returns undefined. How can I fix this?

I noticed that a certain line in Rest_customerdb_customer.js is not working properly.

Below, ref.length is undefined.  How can this be fixed?

/* Method findAll with HTTP request metod GET, its return type is array of Customer  */

```
findAll: function(uri_) 
{
    var url = "";
    if (uri_ != null && uri_ != undefined) {
        url = uri_;
    }
    var remote = new Rest_customerdb_customerRemote(this.uri);
    var c = remote.getJson_(url);

    if (c == -1) 
    {
        return -1;
    }

    var myObj = eval('(' + c + ')');

    var result = new Array();
    for (var prop in myObj) 
    {
        var ref = myObj[prop];


        var j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < ref.length; j++) 
        {
            if (ref[j]['@uri'] != null && ref[j]['@uri'] != undefined) 
            {
                result[j] = new Customer(ref[j], ref[j]['@uri']);
            }
            else 
            {
                result[j] = new Customer(ref[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
},
```